# The Popup Annoyance

Tags: cipher, story

### The story

Fred, a software designer, woke up, got dressed, took a shower, ate breakfast, then headed off for work. He sat down on his chair and booted up his computer, only to see that all the files were gone. Hundreds of popups popped up before his eyes. He tried closing them one by one, only to find that the popups were reappearing the second he closed them. "Dang, I've been hacked," he thought. After four minutes, A new popup appeared. The popup read "ENTER THE PASSWORD:" At the bottom, there was some text that reads "sjE1ycL0DVbgOdWufXX, key=100" Fred thinks about using Caeser Cipher, but he knew that the maximum key is 52. In the corner, it says "YOU ONLY HAVE ONE ATTEMPT. IF YOU FAIL, ALL FILES WILL BE DELETED." Yikes!

Fred tried to restart, but it just said access was denied. He then attempted Ctrl-Alt_Delete, but that still said access was denied.

*What is the password Fred must enter to stop his files from permanently disappearing?*

#### Hints

> I love star wars!
>  BEEP BOOP!
>  Letters and numbers?!

Comment: "got dressed, took a shower, ..." -- Let me guess: Fred is ironing out the bugs in a concurrent task scheduler? `;)`

Comment: Not sure if this is a valid Puzzle or just a "read my mind" type of question. PASSWORD can be "sjE1ycL0DVbgOdWufXX" or same in reverse or same in UPPER CASE or same in lower case Ctrl-Alt-Del to reboot the System. Why ? Or Why Not ? We must have some clues to restrict the Possible Answers and to guide towards the Solution.

Comment: @MOehm , when "all the files were gone", booting might be a bit of a Problem. Hence I am guessing this is more like a "**bare** metal" system : Either the metal clothes will not get wet Or **bare** is actually the dress ....!

Comment: By the way, some users like to downvote without comment feedback, which does not help OP; I use comment feedback to help OP, without downvoting.

Comment: In the Caesar cipher, the maximum key is actually 26 =)

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget 52 if you count uppercase letters.

Comment: rot13({Vg'f npghnyyl dhvgr dhrre gung gurer'f n ahzore va gur pvcuregrkg})